# Protect webmin access with username/password

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, freebsd, password

I just installed `webmin` in my FreeBSD box, now it can be accessed as `http://my-ip.com:10000`, When I enter that address in browser I can see the login page of `webmin` directly. I want to have some additional security by asking username and password to access the login page itself, like that one of `.htpasswd`, any ideas how to achieve that ?

I know how to use `Apache .htaccess` or `Nginx auth_basic` but `webmin` is not using the web server and was not defined too, so, I am quiet lost how to have that username/password field before letting few IPs access that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webmin uses a Miniserv HTTP server, which only has basic IP based allow/deny.

From [Webmin FAQ](http://www.webmin.com/faq.html):

> **How can I change Webmin's list of allowed IP addresses from the shell?**
>
> The file you need to modify is /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf , in particular the allow= or deny= lines. If the allow= line exists, it contains a list of all addresses and networks that are allowed to connect to Webmin. Similarly, the deny= line contains addresses that are not allowed to connect. After modifying this file, you need to run /etc/webmin/stop ; /etc/webmin/start for the changes to take effect. Naturally, the file can only be edited by the root user.

It is possible to use Webmin with Apache; See [Webmin and Apache](http://www.webmin.com/apache.html). Your best bet would be using Apache/Nginx as a proxy to Webmin's Miniserv - make sure to allow connections to webmin miniserv only from localhost to prevent security breaches. Adding the following line to `/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf` should achieve that:

> allow=127.0.0.1

Afterwards you can configure additional security prompts or whichever you need the more familiar and configurable Apache/Nginx.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I don't want to put the webmin overhead to the web-server, so, I was looking if something could be done inwebmin itself. I have used the IP blocking, still I want to have password protection to allowed IPs. Where I work is an umbrella organization which has few public IPs sharing among 150 Organizations and I don't want other table to sneak peak my server.